# añadir variable de entorno custom en react

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

estoy intentando setear variable custom cuando ejecuto npm start o npm run build. Si o si, necesito setear variable al momento de levantar el proyecto o buildear desde la consola de comandos.

Ejemplo:

```
"scripts": {
     "start-algo": "REACT_APP_STAGE=algo react-scripts start",
}
```

y luego ejecutar

```
npm run-start-algo
```

La consola de windows y la de git bash me esta diciendo que no se reconoce el comando:
"REACT_APP_STAGE" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Quisiera saber que otra forma hay de declarar una variable de entorno, preferentemente que no sea de la forma REACT_APP_ (siempre en el package.json). Ya me recorrí toda la documentacion al respecto y no estoy encontrando la solución. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

para usar las variables de entorno deberías usar archivos de entorno, ya que te harán la vida más fácil, cuando uses diferentes entornos para tu aplicación, acá un ejemplo de la [documentación misma](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env).

Y ya si quieres usar variables de diferentes archivos, en un entorno unix podrias usar los comandos **set** y **source** para manejar las variables de entorno del sistema.

Algo asi quedaria el comando en el package.json para usar las varibles de nuestro archivo de entorno, que en este caso seria ".env.custom":

```
"scripts":{
"start-custom": set -o allexport && source .env.custom && set +o allexport && react-scripts start
}
```

Comment: ok, esa puede ser una alternativa. Pregunta es posible indicarle a los diferentes script que carguen determinado .env?
por ejemplo, npm run start-algo que cargue las variables de entorno que estan en .env.development.algo.local
Sucede que tengo varios ambientes y cada ambiente tiene sus respectivas API para produccion y desarrollo.
En realidad tengo 2 ambientes por lo tanto estoy necesitando 4 archivos de configuracion

Comment: ajuste la respuesta para responder tu comentario, espero sea de ayuda

Comment: @FernandoAzarías